# Shopify Template webhookHandlers Error Before Doing Anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-api

I have been trying to learn the basics of building a app for shopify. However I am running in to the issue that right from creating the template in my index.js file. I am not sure what is causing this error as I literally just created the app and have not edited any of the code or added anything. Any help on this would be appreciated, since this is a completely new skill I'm working on learning.

The error I am getting is:

```
Type '{ CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST: { deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod; callbackUrl: string; callback: (topic: any, shop: any, body: any, webhookId: any) => Promise<void>; }; CUSTOMERS_REDACT: { ...; }; SHOP_REDACT: { ...; }; }' is not assignable to type 'WebhookHandlersParam'.
  Property 'CUSTOMERS_DATA_REQUEST' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod; callbackUrl: string; callback: (topic: any, shop: any, body: any, webhookId: any) => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'WebhookHandler | WebhookHandler[]'.
      Type '{ deliveryMethod: DeliveryMethod; callbackUrl: string; callback: (topic: any, shop: any, body: any, webhookId: any) => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'HttpWebhookHandler'.
        Types of property 'deliveryMethod' are incompatible.
          Type 'DeliveryMethod' is not assignable to type 'DeliveryMethod.Http'.
```

**index.js**

```
// @ts-check
import { join } from "path";
import { readFileSync } from "fs";
import express from "express";
import serveStatic from "serve-static";

import shopify from "./shopify.js";
import productCreator from "./product-creator.js";
import GDPRWebhookHandlers from "./gdpr.js";

const PORT = parseInt(process.env.BACKEND_PORT || process.env.PORT, 10);

const STATIC_PATH =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? `${process.cwd()}/frontend/dist`
    : `${process.cwd()}/frontend/`;

const app = express();

// Set up Shopify authentication and webhook handling
app.get(shopify.config.auth.path, shopify.auth.begin());
app.get(
  shopify.config.auth.callbackPath,
  shopify.auth.callback(),
  shopify.redirectToShopifyOrAppRoot()
);
app.post(
  shopify.config.webhooks.path,
  shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers })
);

// All endpoints after this point will require an active session
app.use("/api/*", shopify.validateAuthenticatedSession());

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/api/products/count", async (_req, res) => {
  const countData = await shopify.api.rest.Product.count({
    session: res.locals.shopify.session,
  });
  res.status(200).send(countData);
});

app.get("/api/products/create", async (_req, res) => {
  let status = 200;
  let error = null;

  try {
    await productCreator(res.locals.shopify.session);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(`Failed to process products/create: ${e.message}`);
    status = 500;
    error = e.message;
  }
  res.status(status).send({ success: status === 200, error });
});

app.use(serveStatic(STATIC_PATH, { index: false }));

app.use("/*", shopify.ensureInstalledOnShop(), async (_req, res, _next) => {
  return res
    .status(200)
    .set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    .send(readFileSync(join(STATIC_PATH, "index.html")));
});

app.listen(PORT);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this it's because of typescript.

```
app.post(
  shopify.config.webhooks.path,
  // @ts-ignore
  shopify.processWebhooks({ webhookHandlers: GDPRWebhookHandlers })
);
```